# Yup validation: access form value with useFieldArray

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I’m using a Yup schema with react-hook-form's [useFieldArray](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usefieldarray), and I want to test that each variant’s `pageRedirectId` is not the same as the form’s `pageId`. The problem is that I can’t seem to access the value of the `pageId` from within the test method.

I have tried to access it from the `ctx`, `this` but it’s not there - it only seems to have access to each variant’s form values rather than the entire form values.

Does anyone know a fix for this? Here is my schema:

```
export const schema = (user: User) =>
    Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string().required('Enter a name'),
        websiteId: Yup.string().required('Select a website'),
        pageId: Yup.string().required('Select a page'),
        variants: Yup.array()
            .of(
                Yup.object()
                    .shape({
                        name: Yup.string().required('Enter a variant name'),
                        pageRedirectId: Yup.string(),
                    })
                    .test(
                        'redirects to the same page',
                        'You cannot redirect to the same page. Choose a different page to redirect to',
                        function (value, ctx) {
                            const { pageRedirectId } = value;
                            const pageId = '@todo'; // how can I get the pageId?
                            // @ts-ignore
                            const path = `variants[${ctx.options.index}].pageRedirectId`;

                            if (pageRedirectId === pageId) {
                                return this.createError({
                                    message: 'A variant cannot have the same page redirect as the main page',
                                    path,
                                });
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    )
            )
            .min(2, 'At least one variant is required')
            .required('Add at least one variant')
});
```

The `variants` use react-hook-form’s useFieldArray. I could not seem to use the `when` method either which I have seen in other posts, although I’m not too familiar with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I’m unsure where to go from here, except perhaps pass the entire form’s value to the `createTestSchema` function like how `user` is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2023-07-10: No need for `createError`, simplified code in answer.

The issue here is how to access parent's parent inside `.test`.

The solution is to pass in the context in `.test` and access the schema by using `context.from[1].value`. To get `pageId`, use `context.from[1].value.pageId`.

Please have a look [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/735) for more details about the approach.

Please note that I made some simplifications in your code for brevity. No need for building path in code; it's provided in the context (see below).

```
Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string().required('Enter a name'),
    websiteId: Yup.string().required('Select a website'),
    pageId: Yup.string().required('Select a page'),

    variants: Yup.array(
        Yup.object({
            name: Yup.string().required('Enter a variant name'),
            pageRedirectId: Yup.string()
               .required('Some required text here'),
               .test(
                   'redirects to the same page',
                   'A variant cannot have the same page redirect as the main page',
                   (pageRedirectId, {from}) => // deconstruct of context
                       // @ts-ignore
                       pageRedirectId !== from[1].value.pageId
              )
              ...
```

Code is testet and verified in React/Vite app with similar requirements. yup:1.2.0

Comment: ah, I didn't realise you could just access it from the context like that. Thank you! And I like the improved brevity